# Kotlin android code : JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.Get, ... ) does not work

Tags: android, kotlin

The code:

```
import android.app.DownloadManager
import android.app.DownloadManager.Request
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.textclassifier.TextClassification
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.privacysandbox.tools.core.model.Method
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley



class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        val username = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etUserName);
        val password = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etPassword);
        val btn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button);

        btn.setOnClickListener{
            var url:String="http://www.sepehrfarm.ir/app/read.php?username=" + username.text.toString() + "&password=" + password.text.toString()

            var req : RequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)

            var jos = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.Get,url,null,
                Response.Listener { response -> Toast.makeText(this, "record added" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() } ,
                Response.ErrorListener { error ->  })
        }
    }
}

Request.Method.Get , ...
```

The above code does not work! It does not find the Method from the Request

And I have searched for this problem and found no answer
Your help will be appreciated!

Comment: Need more details,
what library you are getting `Request.Method.Get` ?

Comment: please don't post code as an image as it's not indexable/searchable, plus it makes it difficult to copy it for people who want to help you

Comment: have you checked that you're importing the right `Request` class? You should see `import com.android.volley.Request` at the top of your class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a message error and username and password that you use, its very difficult answer you.

With this code you may committed many errors.

**Problem 1: Error import**

import uncorrect library for Request.Method.Get.

remove

```
import androidx.privacysandbox.tools.core.model.Method
import android.app.DownloadManager.Request
```

and add

```
import com.android.volley.Request
```

**Problem 2: the request is not launched**

Add line

```
req.add(jos)
```

**Problem 3: internet connection**

check if your AndroidManifest.xml contains the line

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**Problem 4: http request instead https request**

from Android 8, all http request needs to use https protocol in url

**solution 1: (reccomanded)**

add character 's' in your string url

```
var url:String="https://www.sepehrfarm.ir/app/read.php?username=" + username.text.toString() + "&password=" + password.text.toString()
```

**solution 2: (not reccomanded)**

add cleartext traffic in your manifest

```
<application
    ...
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    ....
</application>
```